# How to add effect to growl on show?

Tags: primefaces

i have a binded growl, which i set it to be rendered after adding user to database, and i want this growl to have a slide action on show as follows:

```
<p:outputPanel id="idMainGrowl">
<p:growl id="idGrowl" binding="#{myBean.growl}" life="700000" closeable="true" >
            <p:effect type="bounce" event="load" delay="0" >
                <f:param name="mode" value="'show'" />
              </p:effect>
                </p:growl>
</p:outputPanel>
```

but the above code won't work, please advise.

Comment: Please give some more information: What does not work mean? Is the Effect or the growl not visible? Are there any Server or Javascript errors?

Comment: @Sonic, the growl is shown but the effect is not applied and there are no JS errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a little hack for you. I ran into the same problem and solved it by triggering the jquery event like this:

```
<p:growl id="idGrowl" life="3000" closeable="true"  >
        <h:outputScript>
            $("#idGrowl_container").effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2000);
        </h:outputScript>
    </p:growl>
```

You have to apply the effect on your id + "_container". Make sure that your jQuery Selector is pointing to the correct generated id in your jsf page, so watch out for s containing your growl.
To apply bounce effect, just make small changes to the effect as explained below:
http://api.jqueryui.com/bounce-effect/

Comment: when to use toggle and when to use effect ?

Comment: I think Effect is the Method for jQuery UI while toggle is used  in a more general way as it's part of the Standard jquery Library. In your Case use effect:   $( "div" ).effect( "bounce", "slow" );

Comment: the pulsate effect works fine, but the bounce effect won't work at all.